# How do I solve $x^4+44=0$ according to de Moivre?

Tags: complex-numbers

How do I solve $x^4+44=0$ according to de Moivre?

I tried to use the formula, but I got roots that are not beautiful numbers. 
What should the complex roots for this equation be?

Comment: Not all numbers are beautiful.

Comment: Beauty is in the $\pm i$ of the beholder.

Comment: that was really creative thing to say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have

$$x^4=-44=44 e^{i\pi}\implies x=\sqrt[4]{44}\exp\left(\frac{i\pi}4+\frac{ik\pi}2\right),\; k=0,1,2,3 $$